How to enforce TypeScript to catch error when providing too many parameters?
I'm looking for a way to strictly type my function. I want to trigger an error if the params contain more properties than what is defined in its type.
For example, this code does not trigger error:
interface Type1 {
  property1: string;
  property2: string;
}

interface Type2 { 
  property1: string;
};

// the function receive Type1 but expect Type2
// it does not trigger error because all Type2 properties are included in Type1
// i would like it trigger an error because it provide too much parameters
function myFunction(params: Type2) {
  console.log(params);
}

const foo: Type1 = {
  property1: 'foo1',
  property2: 'foo2',
};

myFunction(foo);
// no error triggered
// result: { property1: 'foo1', property2: 'foo2' }

I got the same question (and the same result) with Omit :
type Type2 = Omit<Type1, 'property1'>;


Only property1 is available via the Type2 interface anyway. Excess property checking is only enabled when the only reference to a value is via an interface that doesn't include those properties, which is explicitly not the case here.

Both properties are logged in the console.log. This is not what I expected. In my case, I would like to send "params" into a MongoDB insertion without having to enumerate every field to exclude the undesirable ones. The code provided is an example, but I'm looking for a way to "enable excess property checking," as you said.

You can use something like https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/exact.d.ts

Then do some actual input validation, don't just dump whatever you're given into the DB. TypeScript doesn't exist at runtime anyway so you need that either way.

You absolutely need runtime validation. You can discourage but not prohibit excess properties, as shown in this playground link.

I already have a validation in my controller, then my use-case can add some properties, and then send all this into the service. I would like to be sure that I will not add property that should not, by mistake, in my use-cases. I don't think that I should add also a validation in my service, I think type could handle this, no ?
